# Remove black bands on 2001 Landsat-5 image

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat

Why are there these black strips on this 2001 image of Landsat-5? How can I remove them? They seem to be different from the strips on Landsat-7.

[image]

```
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C02/T1_TOA')
  .filterDate('2001-08-01', '2001-11-30')
    .filterBounds(roi);
print(dataset)

var image=dataset.filter(ee.Filter.eq("system:index", 'LT05_119038_20010819')).first()

var visualization1 = {
  bands: ['B4','B3', 'B2'],
// min: 0.0,
// max: 4000,
};

Map.addLayer( image, visualization1, "False Color (432)");
```